# RegisterPointerInputTarget() function giving false

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf

I am trying to register my C# WPF window for pointer input, so that all the touch input is redirected to it, but the RegisterPointerInputTarget is returning false on being passed the target window handle.
My code is as follows

```
//declarations

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        IntPtr hWnd;
        int abc;
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper windowHwnd = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(this);
            hWnd = windowHwnd.EnsureHandle();
            hWnd = windowHwnd.Handle;
            Minimize.Enable(this);
            this.abc = IWrapper.Rpit(hWnd);
        }
        internal class IWrapper
        {
            const string SHADOW_DLL_NAME = "RPIT_TEST.dll";

            [DllImport(SHADOW_DLL_NAME)]
            public static extern int Rpit(IntPtr hwnd);
        }

    }
}
```

And the RegisterPointerInputTarget function is defined in the RPIT_TEST.dll (as its a c++ function) as follows:

```
extern "C" int __declspec (dllexport) __stdcall Rpit(HWND hwnd)
        {
                typedef enum tagPOINTER_INPUT_TYPE { 
                PT_POINTER  = 0x00000001,
            PT_TOUCH    = 0x00000002,
            PT_PEN      = 0x00000003,
            PT_MOUSE    = 0x00000004
            } POINTER_INPUT_TYPE;
            return RegisterPointerInputTarget(hwnd,PT_POINTER);
        }
```

I have searched a lot for possible errors
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign you application and set the uiAccess flag to true in your manifest file.

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
```

You can also read more about it here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671610(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried debugging my project with uiAccess set to true, I get an error similar to this,
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7a42efab-5ce8-456f-8a58-dfedbc2cefcb/debugging-with-uiaccesstrue
Do you know how to get past this?

Comment: update: I followed steps from here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192504/debugging-with-visual-studio-2012-windows-8-and-user-account-control
and it seems to execute, but the function is still returning false :/